# Is there a way to report errors in Apple documentation?

Tags: ios, macos, documentation

Not a strictly programming question, but surely related.

Is there something like [bugreporter.apple.com‎](http://bugreporter.apple.com) for reporting errors in the official documentation?

I searched a bit but I didn't find anything, neither official nor unofficial.

Comment: If you find the online documentation page it usually has a feedback link at the bottom.

Comment: Oh there it goes! I never noticed that little floating div... Anything else you are aware of?

Comment: I'm aware of many things ;-) Bugreporter does also have a documentation category for new issues...

Comment: Woops, totally missed that too. You're super aware :P Thank you for the info, you can put them in an answer if you like.

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer and the community can decide if this question is worth saving or deleting :-)

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Bugreporter has a documentation specific category
2. Most of the Apple documentation pages have a 'feedback' button at the bottom