# NSArray containsObject not working as advertised

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

So, Apple's documentation says this about `containsObject`:

> This method determines whether anObject is present in the array by
>   sending an isEqual: message to each of the array’s objects (and
>   passing anObject as the parameter to each isEqual: message).

You can find these docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject%3a).

However, I'm experiencing almost the exact opposite effect.  Instead of sending `isEqual:` to each object in my array, the object I provide is getting sent the `isEqual:` message for each object in the array.

For example, I have two classes: `FlxSort` and `FlxFieldKey`.  A `FlxSort` class contains a field key, and I've overridden the `isEqual:` to return true if it's passed a `FlxFieldKey` object that matches the key it holds.  This should in theory allow me to check if a `FlxSort` object is present in the array with a specific key.  However, `FlxFieldKey` isn't (and shouldn't be) aware of the `FlxSort` object, so it will always return false if it's provided a `FlxSort` object in its `isEqual` message.  So in the below code, I would expect each object in `currentSorts` to be sent the `isEqual:` message for each key in `_avialableKeys`.  Instead, each key in `_availableKeys` is sent the `isEqual:` message.  I've checked this both with logging and breakpoints.

```
NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:_avialableKeys.count];
NSArray *currentSorts = _sortGroup.sorts;
for (FlxFieldKey *key in _avialableKeys){
    if (![currentSorts containsObject:key]){
        [keys addObject:key];
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

**Update**
Even though I was asking about `[NSArray containsObject:]` I got a lot of feedback about my implementation of asymmetric equality.  So I want to clarify that my implementation was an experiment born out of curiosity. The original code didn't use `containsObject` at all:

```
NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:_avialableKeys.count];
NSArray *currentSorts = _sortGroup.sorts;
for (FlxFieldKey *key in _avialableKeys){
    BOOL found = NO;
    for (FlxSort *sort in currentSorts){
        if ([sort.key isEqual:key]){
            found = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found){
        [keys addObject:key];
    }
}
```

I was curious if I could rig `containsObject` to work in the above situation. Of course, as has been pointed out by several people, creating asymmetric equality is a bad idea and goes directly against Apple's recommendations. I *could* change the `isEqual:` method in the `FlxFieldKey` to account for `FlxSort` objects, which would restore the symmetric equality between the two classes... sort of.  You could still end up with A == B, A == C, but B != C. And that still leaves the `hash` problem (they need to be the same).

Let me reiterate: *You do not want to do this* (asymmetric equality).  At least, not in production code.  I'm just messing around here seeing what I ***can*** do, not what I ***should*** do. I admit that it was irresponsible of me to not clarify this in the original question as less experienced developers may think this kind of implementation is ok to do.  I apologize for this.

And yes, I will probably report a documentation bug in Radar as soon as I can muster the courage to enter Apple's bug reporter again...

Comment: You should probably do that in your own loop and with your own comparison method. As it is you would be relying on Apple implementation details...

Comment: Yeah, I've already worked around it with my own loop, but it took me a little while to figure out what was going on. I just figured it was safe to assume that it worked the way they said it worked. I asked the question because I want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: This is incredibly dangerous. You've created a situation where A == B but B != A. That is undefined behavior for many algorithms. You should find another approach.

Comment: @RobNapier I've already implemented another approach. This way of using `isEqual` was more of an experiment.  But you're right. I checked the docs for `isEqual` and the hashes would have to be equal, which they are not.

Comment: You should file a bug report. Most likely the outcome of the bug report would be a documentation change.

Comment: Consider using -indexOfObjectPassingTest: or -enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: instead of using -isEqual: and -containsObject: .

Comment: So, we have iOS8 and the same issue exists in the doc.  Did Apple ever respond to your bug report?  Interestingly Java's collections used to implement it as Apple states here way back in 1.4 or maybe 1.3, and then they changed their implementation to match what you've observed in NSArray.  Really annoying at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, it's a discrepancy between the implementation and the documentation and you should [file a bug on radar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039201/is-there-a-way-to-report-errors-in-apple-documentation).

However it served the purpose of highlighting a design issue in your implementation.

The order of comparison really shouldn't matter as the equality

```
[objectA isEqual:objectB] == [objectB isEqual:objectA];
```

should always be true, unless you purposely want to run into troubles.

That being said you I believe a `NSSet` would be much more appropriate for the kind of task, since the `containsObject:` operation executes in constant time, as opposed to linear in case of `NSArray`. In such case you would also need to override the `hash` method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this is what's actually happening, but implementing `containsObject:` as (loosely):

```
for( id containedObj in self ){
    if( [testObj isEqual:containedObj] ){
        return YES;
    }
}
```

means that `testObj`'s `isEqual:` implementation can be cached and called directly, rather than the message being dispatched through `objc_msgSend()` each time. Because `NSArray`s can be heterogenous, it wouldn't be possible to cache every call if the comparison was the other way around, the way the docs say it is.

There's a minor performance gain there that may justify itself for huge arrays.

You should probably file a doc bug, although as Rob Napier pointed out, this is only a problem if you're making equality asymmetric, which is a problematic idea in itself.